# How to ensure URI Permission is correct when opening file?

Tags: android, security

I have file content provider and its given to the other applications to open file.

AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<provider
        android:name="com.sap.mcm.android.content.FileContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.sap.mcm.android.provider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern="/unencrypted/" />
    </provider>
```

By adding this code I assume that applications who has URI permissions can access the file content provider to open a file.

1. Is this assumption right?
2. In this manner is it secured interms of Attacking Vulnerable Content Providers?
3. How to test to ensure there is no security threat by using this above code?

Comment: Since this provider is exported without any permissions, any app that knows a `Uri` for your provider can access the provider to open the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Commons Ware.Correct way of exporting provider with URI Permission   
AndroidMainfest.xml: 
    <provider
        android:name="com.sap.mcm.android.content.FileContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.sap.mcm.android.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true
    </provider>

open a file intent should set the below flag
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way of exporting provider with URI Permission

**AndroidMainfest.xml:**

```
  <provider android:name="com.sap.mcm.android.content.FileContentProvider" 
   android:authorities="com.sap.mcm.android.provider"      
   android:exported="false"  android:grantUriPermissions="true </provider>
```

open a file intent should set the below flag 
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);